# Pandas forward looking window

Tags: python, pandas, series

Hi all so I have been playing around with rolling windows using .rolling() in pandas but it appears that the parameter 'center' only gives you the option to center your window or have it looking into the past. Is there a way to change this and have it look "forwards" without needing to reverse your data? Here is an example of a workaround I found where I reverse the data

```
series.iloc[::-1].rolling('2h', center=False)[::-1]
```

But I was wondering if anyone knew of a less hacky way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this `Series`:

```
dti = pd.date_range('2022-02-22', periods=12, freq='H')
sr = pd.Series(range(len(dti)), index=dti)
print(sr)

# Output
2022-02-22 00:00:00     0
2022-02-22 01:00:00     1
2022-02-22 02:00:00     2
2022-02-22 03:00:00     3
2022-02-22 04:00:00     4
2022-02-22 05:00:00     5
2022-02-22 06:00:00     6
2022-02-22 07:00:00     7
2022-02-22 08:00:00     8
2022-02-22 09:00:00     9
2022-02-22 10:00:00    10
2022-02-22 11:00:00    11
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

Use `shift`:

```
>>> sr.shift(freq='-1H').rolling('2H').mean().reindex(sr.index)
2022-02-22 00:00:00     0.5
2022-02-22 01:00:00     1.5
2022-02-22 02:00:00     2.5
2022-02-22 03:00:00     3.5
2022-02-22 04:00:00     4.5
2022-02-22 05:00:00     5.5
2022-02-22 06:00:00     6.5
2022-02-22 07:00:00     7.5
2022-02-22 08:00:00     8.5
2022-02-22 09:00:00     9.5
2022-02-22 10:00:00    10.5
2022-02-22 11:00:00     NaN
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```